# How to use a self made Type in F#?

Tags: arrays, types, f#

I made a type, but I don't know how to use it properly and I don't found any solution on google.

```
type Sample =
{
    TrackPosition : int
    TubePosition : int
    Barcode : string
}

let arraySamples = Array.create Scenario.Samples.NumberOfSamples **Sample**
BarcodeGenerieren.Samples.Sample
let mutable trackPosition = Scenario.Samples.StartTrackPositions
let mutable index = 1
for i in 1 .. Scenario.Samples.NumberOfSamples do
    let randomNumber = System.Random().Next(0,9999)
    if index > 24 then
        trackPosition <- trackPosition + 1
        index <- 1

    arraySamples.[index] <- **new Sample{TrackPosition= trackPosition, TubePosition =   index, Barcode = sprintf "100%s%06d" ((trackPosition + 1) - Scenario.Samples.StartTrackPositions) randomNumber}**
```

So my question is, what should I changed so that it works, when I will give the type of the array and when I will give the sample with data to the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created what is referred to as a [record type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx).  You can initialise it with the following syntax

```
{TrackPosition = 0;TubePosition = 0;Barcode = "string"}
```

your syntax in the last line is almost correct - it should be

```
arraySamples.[index] <- Sample{
    TrackPosition= trackPosition; 
    TubePosition = index; 
    Barcode = sprintf "100%s%06d" ((trackPosition + 1) - Scenario.Samples.StartTrackPositions) randomNumber}
```

The changes are

1. Eliminate `new`
2. replace `,` with `;`

Comment: Looking at your code, I think you should change the `Array.create ...` to `Array.zeroCreate Scenario.Samples.NumberOfSamples` as you fill in all the entries inside the loop, which was almost correct

Comment: I found it on the MSDN Website